# Create own NFTs only can be sold on own marketplace

Tags: solidity, nft, erc721

I'm facing a challenge with my NFT marketplace project. How I can create NFTs with the rule that those NFTs can only be sold on our own platform but others. Technically is possible, however, I need some help here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this possible For that you have to maintain a mapping or some sort of logic on smart contract level to keep track of whether **to** and **from** address belong to your ERC 721 contract or not.

```
transferFrom(from, to, tokenId)
```

Like when someone mints NFT on your smart contract you can save the address of the minter. And at the time of selling of you can have a condition at the start of transferFrom like.

```
require(to == exists[to], "Warning, You are selling outside of the contract")
```

mapping can be something of like this. mapping(address => address) exists;

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution here. Would you mind providing more detailed information such as an example of Solidity if possible? If I understood you correctly, the logic behind is to leverage the transferFrom function to check whether or not the "to" address is our marketplace customer. Is that right? Otherwise, I would appreciate if you could elaborate more. Thank you